# Error when revoking a user: "Caller does not have authority to revoke"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ca, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to setup a user to be able to register and revoke other users. I use the `fabric-ca-client` command to register a user and enroll like so:

```bash
fabric-ca-client register \
 --id.name user8 \
 --id.affiliation org1 \
 --id.type user \
 --id.attrs 'hf.Registrar.Roles=user,hf.GenCRL=true, admin=true:ecert, hf.Revoker=true' \
 --id.secret user2pw \
 -u http://localhost:7054

fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://user8:user2pw@localhost:7054
```

Then I use it to register another user:

```bash
fabric-ca-client register \
 --id.name user2b \
 --id.affiliation org1 \
 --id.type user \
 --id.secret user3pw \
 -u http://localhost:7054
```

So far, so good. But if try to revoke the newly created user, i get:

```bash
fabric-ca-client revoke -e user2b -r 'keycompromise' -u http://localhost:7054
2022/11/04 11:57:03 [INFO] Configuration file location: /Users/salimbene/.fabric-ca-client/fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
Error: Response from server: Error Code: 71 - Authorization failure
```

And in the fabric CA server I see:

```bash
2022/11/04 11:57:03 [INFO] [::1]:57012 POST /revoke 403 7 "Caller does not have authority to revoke"
```

I cannot figure out why I cannot revoke with my registrar user when its clearly stated in the **attr** property that **hf.Revoker=true**.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the spaces in this line:

```bash
--id.attrs 'hf.Registrar.Roles=user,hf.GenCRL=true, admin=true:ecert, hf.Revoker=true' \
```

There should be NO spaces in the string provided to `--id.attrs`:

```bash
--id.attrs 'hf.Registrar.Roles=user,hf.GenCRL=true,admin=true:ecert,hf.Revoker=true' \
```